# RunAs Prompt for credentials

Tags: batch-file, cmd, runas

I'm trying to write a batch script that will do a RunAs for any given windows service (using explorer.exe to test) for any given user that can be input at time of running. What I currently have is this.

```
set /p Var1="Domain = "
```

`set /p Var2="Username = "`

`set /p Var3="Service to open= "`

`RunAs /user:%Var1%\%Var2% "%Var3%" /seperate`

On command line, this seems to work ok (with coded values instead of variables) but in a batch file it just seems to repeat itself, without opening what it's been specified (it doesn't even prompt for a password, so I can only presume its not even trying). Any idea why it's looping and what I can do to stop it?

Cheers

Comment: Are there any errors coming up? I think your problem may be due to the fact you haven't enclosed your variables in quotation marks (If their values have spaces then this is your problem)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi @Gary Barnett i created something similar to this awhile back.

Here is an example;

```
@ECHO OFF
set /P Domainn=Enter Domain Name: 
set /P Usern=Enter Username: 
set userunas=runas /user:%domainn%\%usern% "

:optionmenu
CLS
ECHO 1 - Control.exe
ECHO 2 - MSinfo32.exe
ECHO 3 - Explorer.exe    
ECHO q - Quit
ECHO.
set /P optionnum=Enter command number: 
GOTO option%optionnum%

:option1
%userunas%control.exe
goto optionmenu

:option2
%userunas% %commonprogramfiles%\micros~1\MSInfo\msinfo32.exe"
goto optionmenu

:option3
%userunas%explorer.exe
goto optionmenu

:optionq
EXIT
```

**Note:** You must run the batch file as Administrator (right-click -> Run as Administrator) or it wont work.

Answer (score 0):

`/seperate` is not a switch from `RUNAS`. So,

```
RUNAS /USER:"%Var1%\%Var2%" "%Var3%"
```

should go fine. If `/seperate` is a parameter to `%Var3%` program, use:

```
RUNAS /USER:"%Var1%\%Var2%" "%Var3% /seperate"
```

You may also add `PAUSE` at end of script so you can check results, while "debugging".